# Android - GridLayout.LayoutParams cannot be cast to RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout

Im trying to use LayoutParams to set the width and height of a RelativeLayout, but get the error `GridLayout.LayoutParams cannot be cast to RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. I'm using this code with the LayoutParams:

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams middleLayoutLayoutParams =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)middleLayout.getLayoutParams();`

I'm not sure why though. It would be pretty easy to solve, just set `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to `GridLayout.LayoutParams`, but the thing is that middleLayout is a `RelativeLayout` and shouldn't be cast to a `GridLayout`.

The reason could be that the parent of `middleLayout` is a `GridLayout`, but I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It is natural to get this error. A child can only have parameters from its parents. A grid layout can't recognize centerHorizontal for example as that is a RelativeLayout parameter. You can only give paramters to children that can be interpreted by the parent. So if the parent is gridlayout it is normal that a child viewgroups getLayoutParams will return gridlayout param type

Comment: Have you try changing id of layout?